# iPhone works fine with car bluetooth for Playing Music but not working for Phone Calls

Tags: iphone, ios, bluetooth

After upgrading to iOS 13.5, I am facing issue while connecting Bluetooth of my car. I am able to connect Bluetooth of car for music and phone calls but after 2-3 minutes Bluetooth for phone gets disconnected and only music is working. Please note I am able to play music continuously.

Please note this was working fine since last 1.5 years before upgrading iOS 13.5, I have upgraded to iOS 13.6 but I am still facing issue.

Also note that I haven’t upgraded car music since the beginning, so I suspect that the issue introduced by iOS upgrade.

Comment: Your first port of call would be the manufacturer of the in-car system. See if they have a firmware update.

Comment: Was it working *before* your upgrade to 13.5?

Comment: @allan 9 It was working since last 1.5 years, after upgrading to 13.5 it starts failing.

Comment: @tejsujin Also the car music system is not updated since I bought car, the only change was iOS upgrade

Comment: That’s an important detail to put in the question, don’t you think?

Answer (score 1):

Buried in the last couple of updates has been a little bug that does this. I think it is tied in with the odd MAC address changing Apple devices can do for security and hiding you from tracking.

The only fix I have found is to delete the pairing on both sides (phone and in-car) and then recreate it. You may get away with just deleying the connection on the Apple but I started in the car system first :-(

Solved exactly the same issue in my Renault after about a month of the phone randomly needing reconnecting even outside a call.